# SQL Map duplicate entries from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Is there a way in SQL to map duplicate entries and get data from another table. I need to map original filename in table 2 but the data is coming from table 1 and use the new filename as mapping reference? I was trying to do ROW_NUMBER with partition but i am not going anywhere

Table 1:

```
new filename       original filename
text_001.pdf       test1333.pdf 
text_001.pdf       test4443.pdf
hello2332.pdf      world1234.txt
hello2332.pdf      world3331.txt
```

Table 2:

```
EE       new filename       
00001    text_001.pdf      
00001    text_001.pdf
00002    hello2332.pdf 
00002    hello2332.pdf
```

Ouput table:

```
    EE       new filename       original filename(entries coming from table 1)
    00001    text_001.pdf       test1333.pdf 
    00001    text_001.pdf       test4443.pdf
    00002    hello2332.pdf      world1234.txt
    000002   hello2332.pdf      world3331.txt
```

Comment: I'd recommend a JOIN! Perhaps a LEFT JOIN, if you also want rows from table2 where the file hasn't been renamed

Comment: `select * from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t1.new_filename = t2.new_filename`?

Comment: There is no general way to do this as the new filename from the first table has no column to separate duplicates.  You need to fix your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH xx AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
[EE],
[new filename]
FROM [Table 2]
)
SELECT 
xx.[EE],
xx.[new filename],
a.[original filename]
FROM xx 
LEFT JOIN [table 1] as a
ON a.[new filename] = xx.[new filename]
```

Comment: The first subquery (using `select distinct`) removes duplicates if any from table2, then a left join to  the original files relates new file to old file. Using a CTE (as shown above) is completely optional.

Comment: @Used_By_Already your idea worked :) thank you. I didn't have to use CTE. What was missing from my query is distinct :)

Comment: what about if i need to update table 2 with the results? i don't think distinct will work?